# xampp fatal error

Tags: php, xampp

I am very new to php, xampp.

I was using xampp for php interacting with phpmyadmin. 
I was working pretty well until xampp mysql stoped working.

For some reason, I could not start mysql, although I was able to start apache.

so, i decided to uninstall xampp and reintall it. however, when i was reinstalling it and choose the blank folder for some process, it said the folder i chose is not empty. so i deleted the phpmyadmin folder inside xampp folder.

Then now it is telling me that alloc: *invalid block*.

I looked up on the internet, but I cannot find the solution.

If someone knows what is going on my laptop, please let me know the solution 
and I am very new to this field, please please explain in as the easiest way as possible.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your old installed xampp is not uninstalled properly. Follow this steps :-

1) Delete 'xampp' folder in 'C:/',

2) Delete 'MySQL' folder in 'C:/Program Files' if there,

3) Delete 'Apache Software Foundation' folder in 'C:/Program Files' if there.

4) Restart your PC/Laptop,

5) Install xampp again.

If you want to prevent your folder data then copy them into a temporary folder. After installation cut them and copy to their relevant locations.

Answer (score 0):

- Try checking if xampp is installed by looking in your C drive.
- Check Windows Uninstall Utility.
- Check if port 80/443 is running. If so, this means that Xampp is installed and running
- Open taskmgr and see if xampp is running.
- Restarting your computer
- Reinstall or try an older version

Comment: yup, after installing older version, it worked. now i am relieved and resume learning. thank you so much

Comment: @vincent can you mark my answer as correct then.